# how to make jQuery load MVC partial view and retrieve model data in one-step

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery code to load an asp.net MVC partial view, the flow is

> jQuery load() => MVC controller => MVC partial view

In my controller, I have a Model list need to display. I tried callback function of load(), but only the partial view html elements are offered, then I plan to write a $.get() under my load() callback function, and write another action method in my controller and return a content(myModelList) to me. Is there any better solution except using `@Html` in my cshtml because it is not as handy as jquery so I don't want to touch it.

Below is my jquery code, the parameter images should come from my backend.

```
function displayGallery(folder) {
    $("#partialView").load("/gallery/getview",
            { folder: folder }, function () {
                $.get('someuri', { folder: folder }, function (images) {
                    var tbl_body = "";
                    data = images;
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        var tbl_row = "";
                        $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                            tbl_row += "<td class=" + "mytd" + " colspan='1'>" + "<div>" + "<img class=" + "'myimg'" + " src=" + v + ">" + "<br/>" + "<p style=" + "text-align:center;" + ">" + k + "</p>" + "</div>" + "</td>";
                        });
                        tbl_body += "<tr>" + tbl_row + "</tr>";
                    });
                    console.log(tbl_body);
                    $("#mytbody").append(tbl_body);
                    console.log("mytbody");
                });
                console.log("load function finished");
            });
        console.log("displayGallery function " + folder);
    }
});
```

Below is my action method:

```
public IActionResult GetView(string folder)
        {
                List<Image> Images = new List<Image>();
                Image image = new Image();
                image.ImageName = "myname";
                image.ImageUri = "myuri";
                Images.Add(image);

                return PartialView("Gallery", Images);
        }
```

Comment: It appears your controller is sending both HTML and images back from one request. So rather than using `$.load()`, use `$.post()` (POST has to be used because you are sending the 'folder'). Once the data arrives, you will need to add the HTML manually, and process the images.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I use $("#partialView").load() to not only load but also bind my partial view with my <div id="partialView"> from my main page, if I use $.post(), then how do I bind them together?

Comment: Once you have the results and the HTML part of the return is in say `data.html`, then you would do this: `$("#partialView").html(data.html)` - that is all the `$.load()` method does for you. Now though, you have your images perhaps in `data.images` - and you can parse those as you have done already. Both of these operations would be done in the callback of the single `$.post()`.